# How to deal with additional model properties required in different views

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model

Say we have simple model:

```
public class Employee{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int ManagerId {get;set;}
 public int ProfileId {get;set;}
}
```

All good, I can add and update Employees. If I need information about the manager on page, I can make a separate request for manager data.
Now, what if I need to display a table with thousands of employees, and I need the Manager name, I cannot make a manager request for each employee. I could replace ManagerId with a Manager object, but in most of the cases it is not needed. We could create a separate model for the given table, but what if you need some other smaller detail in another table that is related to `ProfileId`, we create another model for that to ? We will have to many similar models, it will be a mess, and we need methods to request data for each of them.

What some people do, is that they add `ManagerName` into this model, just a small property, who cares ? And then you need `ProfileName`, so we add that to. And Then another smaller detail we need to show in another table, "no use to create another model just for that, right" ?
The problem is in worst cases that we end up with a model having properties that are not directly related to it, and you have no idea which is what. Different methods in repository will get data for only some of these additional properties which further makes it harder to understand.

What would be the best practices in this case? there is not much info on how to deal with stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best approach is to apply the ViewModel Pattern and create one ViewModel for each View. I know this can sounds like waste of time at first glance, but you have to keep in mind that usually different views have different requirements and fields. This approach is good to have a clear sepparation between your application’s user interface and application logic.

Adopt a consistent name convention is a good way to avoid to get in a mess of obscure viewmodels.

Take a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dphill/2009/01/31/the-viewmodel-pattern/) to get more details about the pattern (the author mentions WPF and Silverlight but the principle is the same to MVC).